# Installed Cartalyst Sentry on Laravel 4 - missing src files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I've installed Sentry on Laravel 4 through composer following [these instructions](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4) but the vendor/cartalyst/sentry/src folder is empty. Why is that? Does anyone know? I didn't get any errors during composer update.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say, during composer update, did you actually try `composer update` or `composer install` ?

Comment: I did `composer update`.

Comment: Maybe you should try `composer install` if it's the first time it appears in your composer.json file. (cf. http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install)

Comment: Nope, it didn't make any difference. I deleted my `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file before running `composer install` and I got the same result.

Comment: Show us (pastebin) your composer.json, please.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry didn't install properly because I also used the fzaninotto/faker package in my app. I guess they just don't work well together. After removing fzaninotto/faker package from my composer.json file and re-running `composer update` it worked perfectly.